# RPT file not readable in notepad?

Tags: rpt

I tried opening an RPT file in Notepad, and it looked like this:

[image]

I then tried opening it in Notepad++, after discovering that it would be more suitable, only to be faced by this:

[image]

Can someone please explain to me what needs to be done to read this file properly?

Comment: *"Can somebody please help explain this to me?"* The title of your question should **be** your question (the shortest possible form of it). Following this guideline, which is in the [help], will improve your odds of getting helpful answers.

Comment: Please follow @T.J.Crowder suggestion. For your question, you are trying to open a binary file, a binary file is a file in a format that only a specialized program can read, in your case, it seems to be from SAP Crystal Reports, may be this can help you: http://www.sap.com/solution/sme/software/analytics/crystal-reports-viewer/index.html

Comment: Notepad/Notepad++ are *text editors*, and you're opening a file that is not *text*. It's a binary file. To *read this file properly*, you need the software that created it. You can view the content in a hex viewer or editor, but it's still going to be a binary file that is not readable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a Crystal Reports RPT file.  You might try opening it in Visual Studio to see if it will render anything useful.  In theory, VS might understand the binary file information, break it down into some sort of object representation and then display for you those objects.

Otherwise, the Crystal Reports software could do the same.

Answer (score 0):

File is binary. Means codified in bytes readable only through the correct program. Which in this case is Crystal report.